# Filtering a ListView with Baseadapter  filters text not images

Tags: android, filtering, baseadapter

There was some progress made to the earlier problem. Now there is a new problem. The text in the GridView shows the correct result. However, the images are the same as at the start of the list.

For example: If I search for "*Sidd*" it displays three results but the photos still start as for the users starting with "**A**". Attached is a screenshot for clarity.

This is the BaseAdapter code:

```
public class TagFriendsAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    List<String> arrayListNames;
    List<String> mOriginalNames;

    List<String> arrayPictures;
    List<String> mOriginalPictures;

    Activity activity;
    String[] fetFriendID;
    String[] fetFriendName;
    String[] fetFriendPicture;

    LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;

    TagFriendsAdapter(Activity a, String[] stringUID, String[] stringName, String[] stringPicture,
            ArrayList<String> arrayName, ArrayList<String> arrayPicture) {

        activity = a;
        fetFriendID = stringUID;
        fetFriendName = stringName;
        fetFriendPicture = stringPicture;

        this.arrayListNames = arrayName;
        this.arrayPictures = arrayPicture;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return arrayListNames.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        if(convertView == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.friends_grid_items, null);

        ImageView imgProfilePicture = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imgProfilePicture);
        TextView txtUserName = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);

        txtUserName.setText(arrayListNames.get(position));

        if (arrayPictures.get(position) != null){
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(arrayPictures.get(position), imgProfilePicture);
        }
        else if (arrayPictures.get(position) == null) {
            imgProfilePicture.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return vi;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {

        Filter filter = new Filter() {

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

                arrayListNames = (List<String>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                ArrayList<String> FilteredArrayNames = new ArrayList<String>();

                if (mOriginalNames == null && mOriginalPictures == null)    {
                    mOriginalNames = new ArrayList<String>(arrayListNames);
                    mOriginalPictures = new ArrayList<String>(arrayPictures);
                }
                if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                    results.count = mOriginalNames.size();
                    results.values = mOriginalNames;
                } else {
                    constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                    for (int i = 0; i < mOriginalNames.size(); i++) {
                        String dataNames = mOriginalNames.get(i);
                        if (dataNames.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString()))  {
                            FilteredArrayNames.add(dataNames);
                        }
                    }

                    results.count = FilteredArrayNames.size();
                    System.out.println(results.count);

                    results.values = FilteredArrayNames;
                    Log.e("VALUES", results.values.toString());
                }

                return results;
            }
        };

        return filter;
    }

}
```

And the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Forgot to +1 the other users answers for having tried to offer a solution and the effort to read through my mess. ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First refactor your code. Create a class that holds name, picture and other friend data together.

```
class Friend {
    public String name;
    public String picture;
    ... /* more members and access methods*/
};
```

Then modify your adapter and filtering code accordingly.

- `FilterResults` should contain the `ArrayList<Friend>`, i.e. a list of `Friend` objects and not just the names.
- In Adapter, replace

  `List<String> arrayListNames;`
  `List<String> arrayPictures;`

  with

  `List<Friend> friendsList;`
- Change the `getView` method to access data from the `friendsList` object list.

After these changes the code will look better and work better.

### Update:

Make sure your adapter's `getItem` method returns a `Friend` object

```
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mFriendsList.get(position);
}
```

Comment: Could you add a little more detail to the answer you have posted? I have tried the first two questions and none of them work. I would ideally love to spend more time trying to debug either of those two solution's but your suggestion seems to make more sense going forward. For example, in the first suggestion you make, refactoring the code bit, you mean move the entire portion where I parse the JSON result to this class?

Comment: Perhaps I could repost my entire Activity that sends the data to this adapter again. If that helps.

Comment: create a list of `Friend` objects from the JSON data. In a loop, create a new `Friend` object and add it to an `ArrayList`. Each `Friend` object will represent a single friend info.

Comment: Is there a working example I can borrow some logic from? Your answer is a little vague from my point of view. Again, if I had the time, I would research and find out, but unfortunately, I don't. Sorry to say, but an example is the need of the hour.

Comment: I think theres no other approach that will work for filtering in your case. As you have 2 differnt list for your data...and you can return only 1 list of results in your `performFiltering` method. So you got to make a single object(containing name and picture) for it to work.

Comment: Here is an example: http://www.mokasocial.com/2010/07/arrayadapte-filtering-and-you/

Comment: I understand that. And I also realize that your solution is going to be the best way going forward and not just for this situation, but generally speaking. But I much prefer an example. Not necessarily specific to my problem, but an example which leads me to implement your suggestion. The first code block in your answer specifically. The rest I suppose I can figure out. But getting all data into a class as mentioned is what I need an example for.

Comment: My bad. The link came as I was typing the comment. :-(

Comment: through refactoring? or got it working with your original code..?

Comment: No no. To implement your first suggestion to refactor. Found a tutorial: http://geekswithblogs.net/bosuch/archive/2011/01/31/android---create-a-custom-multi-line-listview-bound-to-an.aspx to implement the custom List<Friend>. Will work on the rest of your suggestion as soon as I have that working. The search will follow as soon as that is in place. :-) But I seem to be on the right track so far. I doubt the original code would have ever worked after seeing your suggestion.

Comment: Ok. That worked. Just one more thing though. I think it crashed once after I clicked on an item in the grid view and open the Users profile and then his album. When I clicked back all the way to the friends page again when the crash occurred. Is there anyway I can save the search state?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help fella. Answer selected and bounty awarded. :-)

Answer (score 6):

Problem is because you are not updating the list of picture names while you filter the array based on edittext input, you also need to update them too,

I have tried to modify your code,check this

```
    public static List<String> temparrayPictures; 
    public static List<String> temparrayListNames; 
    public class TagFriendsAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable { 

        List<String> arrayListNames; 
        List<String> arrayPictures; 

        Activity activity; 
        String[] fetFriendID; 
        String[] fetFriendName; 
        String[] fetFriendPicture; 

        LayoutInflater inflater = null; 
        ImageLoader imageLoader; 

        TagFriendsAdapter(Activity a, String[] stringUID, String[] stringName, String[] stringPicture, 
                ArrayList<String> arrayName, ArrayList<String> arrayPicture) { 

            activity = a; 
            fetFriendID = stringUID; 
            fetFriendName = stringName; 
            fetFriendPicture = stringPicture; 

            this.arrayListNames = arrayName; 
            this.arrayPictures = arrayPicture; 
            temparrayPictures = arrayPicture;
            temparrayListNames = arrayName;

            inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
            imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext()); 
        } 

        public int getCount() { 
            return temparrayListNames.size(); 
        } 

        public Object getItem(int position) { 
            return position; 
        } 

        public long getItemId(int position) { 
            return position; 
        } 

        @Override 
        public void notifyDataSetChanged() { 
            super.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
        } 

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
            View vi = convertView; 
            if(convertView == null) 
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.friends_grid_items, null); 

            ImageView imgProfilePicture = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imgProfilePicture); 
            TextView txtUserName = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txtUserName); 

            txtUserName.setText(temparrayListNames.get(position)); 

            if (temparrayPictures.get(position) != null){ 
                imageLoader.DisplayImage(temparrayPictures.get(position), imgProfilePicture); 
            } 
            else if (temparrayPictures.get(position) == null) { 
                imgProfilePicture.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
            } 

            return vi; 
        } 

        @Override 
        public Filter getFilter() { 

            Filter filter = new Filter() { 

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
                @Override 
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) { 

                    notifyDataSetChanged(); 
                } 

                @Override 
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) { 

                    FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                    temparrayPictures.clear();
                    temparrayListNames.clear();

                    if (temparrayListNames == null && temparrayPictures == null)    { 
                        temparrayListNames = new ArrayList<String>(arrayListNames); 
                        temparrayPictures = new ArrayList<String>(arrayPictures); 
                    } 
                    if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) { 
                        results.count = arrayListNames.size(); 
                        results.values = arrayListNames; 

                        temparrayPictures = arrayPictures;
                        temparrayListNames = arrayListNames;
                    } else { 
                        constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase(); 
                        for (int i = 0; i < mOriginalNames.size(); i++) { 
                            String dataNames = arrayName.get(i); 
                            String picNames =  arrayPicture.get(i);
                            if (dataNames.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString()))  { 
                                temparrayPictures.add(picNames);
                                temparrayListNames.add(dataNames);
                            } 
                        } 

                        results.count = temparrayListNames.size(); 
                        System.out.println(results.count); 

                        results.values = temparrayListNames; 
                        Log.e("VALUES", results.values.toString()); 
                    } 

                    return results; 
                } 
            }; 

            return filter; 
        } 

    }
```

Comment: Although, It needs more memory for temp lists but anyways good for few  requirements. mOriginalNames should be arrayName

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
public class TagFriendsAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable
{

    List<String> arrayListNames;
    List<String> mOriginalNames;

    List<String> arrayPictures;
    List<String> mOriginalPictures;

    Activity activity;
    String[] fetFriendID;
    String[] fetFriendName;
    String[] fetFriendPicture;

    LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;

    private Hashtable<String, String> picturesMap = new Hashtable<String, String>();

    public void setNamesAndPictures(List<String> arrayListNames, List<String> arrayPictures) {
        for(int i = 0; i < arrayListNames.size(); i++){
            picturesMap.put(arrayListNames.get(i), arrayPictures.get(i));
        }

        this.arrayListNames = arrayListNames;
    }

    TagFriendsAdapter(Activity a, String[] stringUID, String[] stringName, String[] stringPicture,
            ArrayList<String> arrayName, ArrayList<String> arrayPicture) {

        activity = a;
        fetFriendID = stringUID;
        fetFriendName = stringName;
        fetFriendPicture = stringPicture;

        this.arrayListNames = arrayName;
        this.arrayPictures = arrayPicture;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayListNames.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        if(convertView == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.friends_grid_items, null);

        ImageView imgProfilePicture = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imgProfilePicture);
        TextView txtUserName = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);

        txtUserName.setText(arrayListNames.get(position));

        String url = picturesMap.get(arrayListNames.get(position));
        if(url != null){
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(url, imgProfilePicture);
        }
        else if(arrayPictures.get(position) == null){
            imgProfilePicture.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return vi;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {

        Filter filter = new Filter() {

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

                arrayListNames = (List<String>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                ArrayList<String> FilteredArrayNames = new ArrayList<String>();

                if(mOriginalNames == null && mOriginalPictures == null){
                    mOriginalNames = new ArrayList<String>(arrayListNames);
                    mOriginalPictures = new ArrayList<String>(arrayPictures);
                }
                if(constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0){
                    results.count = mOriginalNames.size();
                    results.values = mOriginalNames;
                }
                else{
                    constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                    for(int i = 0; i < mOriginalNames.size(); i++){
                        String dataNames = mOriginalNames.get(i);
                        if(dataNames.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString())){
                            FilteredArrayNames.add(dataNames);
                        }
                    }

                    results.count = FilteredArrayNames.size();
                    System.out.println(results.count);

                    results.values = FilteredArrayNames;
                    Log.e("VALUES", results.values.toString());
                }

                return results;
            }
        };

        return filter;
    }

}
```

Comment: I am sorry, but what FilterResults class? You mean the source that is sent to this adapter?

Comment: And the fact that my 'arrayPictures' never changes is the source of the problem. My filtering is done on the user's name. How do I link the name with the position of the picture is the problem I suspect.

Comment: @SiddharthLele Create a hash that store URL with user name. Then when you apply the name you will have access to the image URL

Comment: @SiddharthLele yep! If you got less then 10,000 records it will do the job, if you got more then that, then use database

Comment: Hmm... Could you point me to an example, or suggest changes in my own code? I had added the original activity earlier when  started the thread and can add it back up if you would want it.

Comment: @SiddharthLele check it out, just call to setNamesAndPictures

Answer (score 1):

@MKJParekh did a great job!To sum up his implementation:

1. **Declare a temporary List of objects at the beginning of the class** that reflect the incoming data used for each item (1 object per item).
2. In the `performFiltering()`set the condition for nulls and empty strings, and also **if the constraint matches the string value of the corresponding object, then add the object to the temp List.** That way you have only a "filtered" list of objects.
3. **Use data from your temp list, rather than your data source** (as you normally would), for methods such as `getCount()`, `getItem()`, and `getView()`. Otherwise, you'll just be loading ALL the items everytime, since untimately `notifyDataSetChanged()` will be called after each filtering.